# Lag in deployment of VF page to Force.com Site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I'm in the middle of debugging a new VF page that is being deployed on a Force.com Site.  While I'm iterating through several rounds of bug fixing and UI tweaking, I like to save my code and refresh the site to see what it looks like.  Since this is a Site nobody is using yet, I'm not using the sandbox -- I'm doing this straight in production.

The strange issue is this: sometimes when I save the code and refresh the Site, I see my changes immediately.  But other times I see my old page when I refresh.  If I look at it in another browser, I might see my old page or my new page.  Usually after 10 or 15 minutes, I see the new page in all browsers and all tabs.  However, it's really annoying to have to wait a non-deterministic amount of time whenever I make a small tweak to the page.

What is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a hint , not sure if this is exactly what you might need.

Check the `cache = false` in your `apex:page` component

Good read here : Michael exactly speaks about your issue :

http://www.michaelforce.org/blogView?id=a0D300000043TF8EAM

QUESTION:

> So the problem I ran into with Sites was that I would make a change to
>   a page, or maybe to the data in an object which is being displayed on
>   a page and it would take up to several minutes before the change would
>   show up on my site. At first I thought it was the browser, so I would
>   try clearing my cache and refreshing... no dice.

ANSWER:

> "There is a property on the Visualforce "apex:page" component called
>   "cache". You can set it to "false" to tell the salesforce servers that
>   they should not cache the page."